# Eclipse shortcuts strange behaviour when using function keys (F11-F12)

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

While coding in eclipse I like to use the editor window full screen (ctrl-m).
To make the package explorer and console windows quickly accessible, I tried to edit their shortcuts:

```
Preferences->Keys:
Show View (Console): Ctrl+Alt+F11
Show View (Package Explorer): Ctrl+Alt+F12
```

When I try to use these new shortcuts they don't seem to work. There are no conflicting shortcuts.
I don't understand this, why this strange behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Let's start with some more details... Eclipse version? Your operating system?

Comment: SpringSourceToolSuite 3.5.0 which is based on eclipse 4.3.2. Operating system: windows 7 32 bit. Java version: 1.7u51.

Comment: I tried and can't reproduce this on my box. Eclipse shortcuts work just as they should.

Comment: Ok thanks nowaq, I'll try a new version of eclipse and see if it solves the problem.